# Conversion of a date data types to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an out of range value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was trying to insert a date type columns but I'm getting an error mentioned in title

```
insert into table (Date)
select date from dbo.source
```

The date in dbo.source is of date data type and Date in Table is of smalldatetime data type, so when I try to insert i'm getting error as mentioned in title.
I try to use `convert(smalldatetime,date)`, but still I'm facing an issue.
Anyone can help on this?

Answer (score 3):

I think in your `dbo.source` table there are records which is out of range of `smalldatetime` range.
Try this to find such out-of-range records  -

```
select date
from dbo.source
where date < '1900-01-01' or date > '2079-06-06'
```

SmallDateTime range - `1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06`

Date range - `0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31`

Answer (score 2):

You probably have dates in your table out of this range 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06, which is for smalldatetime. Date has a range of 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31. You have to cap the dates to fit into smalldatetime.

Answer (score 2):

Either insert NULL for the values that don't fit:

```
insert into table (Date)
select try_cast(date as smalldatetime) from dbo.source
```

Or don't insert these rows at all:

```
insert into table (Date)
select date from dbo.source
where try_cast(date as smalldatetime) is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Please, try with below query with range of date time datatype:

```
insert into table (Date)
   select  date from dbo.orders
     where date between '1900-01-01 00:00:00' and '2079-06-06 23:59:00'
```